# СУБД Базы данных лиензирование

Tags: mysql, sql, лицензирование

не знаю какую СУБД целесообразней будет поставить...
Имеется физический магазин где 10 терминалов и сайт 
который постоянно взаимодействует с **1C** ее базой и сверяеться, пока что хранение данных осуществляется системой 1с(файловая вроде как).
 
Суть в том что она категорически не устраивает и хотелось бы sql!
Посмотрев в сторону **MySQL** был удивлен стоимость в **2000 $ / в год**.
Пока что это слишком круто, у нас в номенклатуре около **15000 записей**.
Хотелось бы что-то дешево и сердито что можете посоветовать?
Если можно помимо продуктов увидеть коротко их отличия...

Comment: Брать коммерческую оракловую версию MySQL нет никакой необходимости. Возьмите бесплатную версию от оракла (Community server). Или форк MariaDB или percona MySQL https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-server (у нее и производительность получше, так как переделан движок innoDB)

Comment: @Mike, а использование данной версии в коммерческих целях не чревато? потому что я честно говоря думал что она для разработчиков для тестов...И в моем случае да бы не было проблем с законом нужно приобрести лицензию...

Comment: Вообще она под GPL лицензией, которая вообще не запрещает никакое использование продукта (кроме коммерческого распространения самой СУБД). А вот как вам "купить" бесплатную лицензию не знаю, это надо с юристами советоваться

Comment: @Mike вы имеете ввиду под GPL, Community edition или все версии MySQL, а деньги взымаются за такие опции как поддержка и прочее?

Comment: @Mike спасибо, нашел то о чем выговорил. Cудя по всему лицензия позволяет ваш проект распространять не под лицензией **GPL**.
А именно в случае использования в своем проекте MySQL код(к примеру MySQL Connector) ваш проект имеет лицензию **GPL** и код этого проекта становиться открытым...